# Cannot activate any programs except Chrome -> coreservicesd crash

Tags: google-chrome

I suddenly started experiencing an error in which Chrome is the only application that will accept any input. I can use the mouse to bring other windows to the front, but they will not accept keyboard input.  The Dock also won't accept input - I can't apple-tab between applications.  If I hide Chrome, it still accepts keyboard input!  Any ideas on what would cause this or what a solution might be?  (I will attempt the "close chrome, restart" workaround, but that doesn't qualify as a solution)

Closing chrome just revealed that the whole OS had crashed.  A little more research revealed others have experienced this:
http://www.macsupportguy.com/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=47208

The errors in my system.log include:

```
Jan 16 12:12:41 eta /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/MacOS/Dock[195]: LaunchServices/5123589: coreservicesd is running an unsupported version, 0       ( we are 10600000 ), so we cannot talk to it.
Jan 16 12:12:41 eta /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/MacOS/Dock[195]: LaunchServices: _LSDoInitializeProcessesServices() returned 268435459, err      =-1  vers=0, we are 10600000. sessionID=0x2d00012
```

I'm on OS 10.6.8, but others ran into this (also with Chrome running) on 10.7.

The core of the crash may be this:

```
Jan 16 12:05:01 eta [0x0-0x17db7da].com.apple.systemevents[95826]: launchctl: CFURLWriteDataAndPropertiesToResource(/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd.perus      er.501/overrides.plist) failed: -10
Jan 16 12:10:02 eta loginwindow[70]: CarbonCore.framework: coreservicesd process died; attempting to reconnect but future use may result in erroneous behavior      .
Jan 16 12:10:02 eta hdiejectd[46853]: CarbonCore.framework: coreservicesd process died; attempting to reconnect but future use may result in erroneous behavio      r.
```

Others reported having no access to the UI and being forced to hard-restart the machine; I was able to reboot by `ssh`ing in and doing `sudo reboot`.  However, it would be best to come up with a solution to recover the machine rather than restart it - I lost a lot of work in this random crash.